# What caused a colour change when I mixed two different dish soaps?

Tags: organic-chemistry, color, cleaning, soap

I recently purchased "organic" dish soap refill made from saponified coconut oil and potassium soap ([full ingredient list](https://www.cleancult.com/products/dish-soap-refill-lemongrass-32oz/)). Instead of waiting for the old dish soap (Dawn) to be completely finished, I just poured the refill into the bottle.

The refill was a translucent yellow, and Dawn is obviously translucent blue. However, as soon as they made contact with each other, some chemical reaction clearly happened and the whole thing turned into opaque dark brown. The resulting liquid still has cleaning properties but doesn't seem to be equivalent to either of the soaps alone.

I tried to figure out what could have possibly reacted, but couldn't figure it out. Thought I'd try here.

Comment: As every painter is aware, mixing two colors can result in another color. It is doubtful any chemical reaction took place.

Comment: Yellow and blue makes green (not dark brown). Plus the change in translucency, consistency and cleaning property of the liquid points to a chemical reaction.

Comment: @EdV, DAWN dishwashing liquid is not very stable with respect to strong alkalis and bleach. I have smelled ammonia like smell from decomposition.

Comment: @M.Farooq All the more reason not to mix chemicals at home! At least it was not bathroom cleaning products. So the solution is to flush it down the drain.

Comment: @EdV some things are learnt the hard way by follies. It is always a bad idea of mix cleaning products or even soaps.